# How do you convert a .h5 file to .csv?

Tags: csv, file-conversion

I downloaded a large data set that is in the form of a .tar.gz file.

Unpacking yields several folders of data and each individual data file is in the form of a .h5 file. I need to convert the data into a .csv or .tsv format so that I can easily import it into and use it in R.

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: `tar xzvf filename.tar.gz` unpacks the tar file.  That part is easy.  Your real question seems to be what to do what the h5 files.

Comment: If this is a public dataset, perhaps you could provide a link so other people can better help you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what OS you are using but here is a man page for tar. [man tar](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tar)

Answer (score 0):

You can read .h5 files with R using the packages rhdf5 (Bioonductor, not CRAN) or h5.  Many .h5 files contain sparse matrices, so downstream applications might require converting them into standard matrix form.